# Darwin/Quicktime Streaming Server how to re-stream an HTTP video stream?

Tags: video-streaming, video

I want to configure Darwin/Quicktime Streaming Server to re-stream an HTTP stream coming from Adobe Media Server.

Can anyone recommend me a Idea how I could implement it?